# datagrid column value not displaying c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a business object that returns a list of objects. This list is then being used as a datasource for a datagridview on a winform. I load my list, set it to the datasource, refresh and view. One of the columns is present but has no values. I see the header but no data. The column is for TruckColorId. Id shows the correct value. Debugging the code I can see that there are objects in the list with all the properties I expect to see correctly with data, including the field in question.

If I select a row and do a foreach loop of the selected row all columns have value but the TruckColorId.

```
public class TruckColor : EditBase 
{
   public int TruckColorId { get; set; }
   public override int Id
   {
    get { return TruckColorId; }
    set { TruckColorId = value; }
   }
}

public class EditBase
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public string ShortCode { get; set; }        
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IList<EditBase> GetAll()
    {
        return new List<EditBase>()
        {
            new TruckColor
            {
                Description = "abc",
                Id = 1,
                ShortCode = "A"
            },
            new TruckColor
            {
                Description = "abcd",
                Id = 2,
                ShortCode = "B"
            },
            new TruckColor
            {
                Description = "abcde",
                Id = 3,
                ShortCode = "C"
            },
        };
    }
  }
```

And here is the code in my form to load the trucks:

```
public void InitTrucks()
{
    TruckColor truck = new TruckColor();

    var trucks = truck.GetAll();
    if (trucks.Count() > 0)
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;                
        dataGridView1.DataSource = trucks;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked fine for me: https://pastebin.com/6adxiEnU

Comment: After using the example Perdo posted I realized I am doing something very different than would be expected. I have revised my code example a little to include the changes. Basically the "GetAll" method is implemented in the base class and not in the derived class since it shares common functions. The var trucks = truck.GetAll() returns a list of the truck objects and I can see that the TruckColorId is in the collection. The datagridView does not include this. I can only assume it is because it is treating it as an EditBase and not Truck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var trucks = truck.GetAll();
 if (trucks.Count() > 0)
{
    List<TruckColor> RealTrucks = trucks.Select(x=>(TruckColor)x).ToList();
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;                
    dataGridView1.DataSource = RealTrucks;
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Wonderful!  This allowed the list to display as I would expect a list of trucks to display.